# C++ level nodeJS module loading

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, node-modules

I am developing a NodeJS module and its file size is increasing dramatically, however I have realized that I can divide my module into two separate modules. When this happens only a few functions in my second module need to use internal C++ classes of my first module. Is it possible to somehow only pass the prototype of the first module to the second one?

Example:

**Module A**:
Has a class called `cModuleA`:

```
class cModuleA {
    //declarations
    data* pointer;
}
```

**Module B**:
Has about 100 function but only one of them needs to manipulate `data*` pointers. It needs to return `cModuleA` object as well (therefore it needs a prototype of `cModuleA` or be aware of `cModuleA` implementation)

I have tried to export symbols from the first module (`dllimport/dllexport` in windows) but I was just wondering if there is any better option to inject dependencies at C++ level.

Comment: Check out http://programmaticallyspeaking.blogspot.com/2010/04/beautiful-dependency-injection-in-c.html

Comment: @ToddMoses In that case both `Foo` and `NeedFoo` live in the same package (aka they are aware of each other's implementations) but here I have my `Module A` in another binary and `Module B` in the other.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem and I am going to go over it in detail since probably nobody else has attempted to do such a crazy thing!

Assume you have **two** native node modules. Meaning that they live in separate executable files (.node). One of them is moduleA and the other one is moduleB:

**ModuleA**:

```
class cppClass
{
public:
    cppClass();
    ~cppClass();
    // C++ stuff here
}; // !class cppClass

class cppClassWrap
    : public node::ObjectWrap
{
public:
    // used for initializing this class for Node/v8
    static void Initialize(v8::Handle<Object> target);
    // internal C++ data accessor
    cppClass* GetWrapped() const { return internal_; };
    // internal C++ data accessor
    void SetWrapped(cppClass* n)  { internal_ = n; };
private:
    cppClassWrap();
    cppClassWrap(cppClass*);
    ~cppClassWrap() { if (internal_) delete internal_; };

    // JS stuff here

    static Persistent<Function> constructor;
    // JS c'tor
    static NAN_METHOD(New);
    // internal C++ data
    cppClass* internal_;
}; // !class cppClassWrap

//-------------------------------------------------
// JS c'tor implementation
NAN_METHOD(cppClassWrap::New)
{
    NanScope();
    cppClassWrap* obj;
    if (args.Length() == 0)
    {
        obj = new cppClass();
    }
    // **** NOTICE THIS! ****
    // This is a special case when in JS land we initialize our class like: new cppClassWrap(null)
    // It constructs the object with a pointer, pointing to nothing!
    else if (args[0]->IsNull())
    {
        obj = new cppClass(nullptr);
    }
    else
    {
        //copy constructor for the JS side
        obj = new cppClassWrap(ObjectWrap::Unwrap<cppClassWrap>(args[0]->ToObject())->GetWrapped());
    }
    obj->Wrap(args.This());
    NanReturnValue(args.This());
}
```

From this point on, all you need to do is to for example have `Persistent` handle in `ModuleB` to store a copy of the constructor of `ModuleA`'s class c'tor in it. For example you can have a method called `dependencies` and call it in JS like:

```
var cppClassWrap = require("ModuleA.node").cppClassWrap;
var moduleB = require("ModuleB.node").dependencies({
    "moduleA" : function() {return new cppClassWrap(null); }
});
```

And done! you have module injection at C++ level!